# python dictionary keys are string and values are a list of floats; how to filter with cutoff?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using python.

I have a dictionary; where keys are "ASN A  74" (bold face) and the values are list of floats. I would like to check if each float value of a list <= 50.00 and it should return me keys of the corresponding values if it passes the above condition.

Here are a few lines of sample data:

**ASN A  74**  `[60.88, 57.21, 54.43, 52.94, 58.27, 59.37, 61.42, 60.15]`

**LYS A  72**  `[76.41, 74.61, 73.91, 73.82, 74.27, 74.17, 72.36, 70.58, 70.12]`

**TYR A  75**  `[48.85, 45.25, 42.33, 41.89, 46.64, 47.71, 47.23, 46.54, 46.32, 46.61, 45.16, 46.0]`

**ASP A  73**  `[72.02, 70.8, 66.95, 65.35, 73.96, 75.88, 76.19, 77.57]`

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a dictionary:

```
for k, v in dct.items():
    if all(i <= 50 for i in v):
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

`all` returns `True` if all of the elements in an iterable are true.

```py
d = {
    "ASN A 74" : [60.88, 57.21, 54.43, 52.94, 58.27, 59.37, 61.42, 60.15],

    "LYS A 72" : [76.41, 74.61, 73.91, 73.82, 74.27, 74.17, 72.36, 70.58, 70.12],

    "TYR A 75" : [48.85, 45.25, 42.33, 41.89, 46.64, 47.71, 47.23, 46.54, 46.32, 46.61, 45.16, 46.0],

    "ASP A 73" :[72.02, 70.8, 66.95, 65.35, 73.96, 75.88, 76.19, 77.57]
}

result = [k for k,v in d.items() if all(map(lambda x: x<=50.0, v))]

print(result) #['TYR A 75']
```